# How to add text above grid cells?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, css-grid

New to js here. I want to label my chessboard with numbers and letters that are place next to the edge of the board. However, I could not find an abstract way to do so. So far, I only have the chessboard created with colors (not shown).

HTML:

```
<div id = 'gridcontainer'> 

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function makeChessBoard(row, col)           //creates 64 cells
        {
            grid = document.getElementById('gridcontainer');
            grid.style.cssText = "grid-template-columns: repeat(" + col + ", 60px);

            cell = [];
            for (i = 0; i < (row * col); i++)
            {
                cell[i] = document.createElement('div');
                cell[i].className = 'cells';

                grid.appendChild(cell[i]);
            }
        }
makeChessBoard(8, 8);
```

CSS:

```
#gridcontainer
{
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0;
}
```

Please, any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It,s better to make yor cell array 2d. And you can make +1 row and col and put numbers and letters in them using 'if'. Then add them special class. Something like that.

```
function makeChessBoard(row, col){           //creates 64 cells
  grid = document.getElementById('container');
  grid.style.cssText = "grid-template-columns: repeat(" + col + ", 60px)"
  const leters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
  cell = [];
  for (i=0; i<row+1; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<col+1; j++) {
      cell[i][j] = document.createElement('div');
      cell[i][j].className = 'cells';
      if(cell[i][col]) {
        this.innerText = leters[j]
      }
      if(cell[row][j]) {
        this.innerText = j+1
      }
      grid.appendChild(cell[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to S/O - and thank you for actively contributing! :) Please consider expanding on your answer in order to explain _why_ your option would be better. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is well worth reading as well.